# "Software installation failed" for Wordpress Deployment in GCP

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I set up my wordpress "Google Click To Deploy" a year ago and the website has been working fine until a month ago.

I then go to deployment manager page for the instance and saw this error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56tGb.png)

Can someone explain what can I do with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*(sorry this should be a comment but I only have reputation enough to write answers)*

Please check the logs related with "Deployment" or "Wordpress" using the Advanced Filter of Google Cloud Logs

```
resource.type="deployment"
resource.labels.name="wordpress-1"
```

Or directly pressing [on this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?expandAll=false&resource=deployment%2Fname%2Fwordpress-1&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22deployment%22%0Aresource.labels.name%3D%22wordpress-1%22%0A) to open Google Stackdriver Loggin with these specific filters already applied.